# Moving from HeroEngine to Unity/Torque 3D

Tags: unity, torque

Short background: small team with some financial back-up from investors, yet no multi-billion-$ enterprise, working on an MMORPG for PC.

HeroEngine looks like the perfect solution. Everything included that's needed to get started, programming languages also include C++/C#. Sounds perfect.

However, once the money's rolling in, a company might prefer work on its own, including its own server park, etc.

Does anyone have experience in using HeroEngine? Is it possible to migrate projects from it to Unity/Torque 3D or the like? Are there legal restrictions (I had a look into the license agreements yet was unable to find an answer to this)?

Should they get started with HeroEngine and the migrate later or is it wiser to choose an engine like Unity/Torque 3D from the get-go?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend planning to switch engines. You should always develop in the game engine you ultimately intend to use. The only possible exception is when prototyping, and that doesn't sound like what you're asking about.

That said, Hero Engine looks like a fine choice for the entire project. There is one obvious advantage to Unity: it's cross platform. I think Hero is Windows only. If you do want to learn about Unity, you should check out my book http://www.manning.com/hocking/

Comment: @jhocking : thank you, I expected this answer. I never found it a good idea to switch (I'm "just" the manager, not a programmer in the team, so no deeper technical knowledge from my side) but accounting kept giving me figures about why we should start with HeroEngine and then switch... I will have a closer look at the book as well as a major issue we have is procedural terrain (which is mandatory and of which I heard that Unity is not good at handling it).

Comment: plugs are allowed as long as they're relevant and clearly marked as such. oh well

Comment: `accounting kept giving me figures about why we should start with HeroEngine and then switch` whoah whoah whoah why does *accounting* have any say in your team's technology choices? That in and of itself seems like a bad sign, regardless of what choice is ultimately made. Technology choices should be made by engineers.

Comment: re procedural terrain: It's not so much that Unity is bad at handling it, as there's nothing built-in for procedural terrain. If Hero has built-in support then that's a consideration; in Unity you'd be building a procedural terrain system (or perhaps you can buy something from the Asset Store; google 'unity asset store procedural terrain' to see what I mean.)